# cytoscape doesn't display edge labels and attributes for GraphML file?

Tags: cytoscape

I import the "tinkerpop-classic.xml", which is graphML file from the TinkerPop gremlin's sample data directory  into Cytoscape. However, it doesn't show the labels and attributes on the Edge. How can I show the full labels in both nodes and edges? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Cytoscape doesn't show edge labels.  To show them, go to the Edge tab in the Style panel and create a passthrough mapping from the desired edge column to the Label.

-- scooter